# How to differentiate between ferri-magnetic and para-magnetic substances?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Both are feebly attracted by a magnetic field. I know the difference between these substances(on why these get attracted to magnetic field) but as both get feebly attracted how to find out whether a given substance is ferri-magnetic or para-magnetic?

Is it that all ferri-magnetic materials are compounds of different metals like magnetite and we can differentiate in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Refer NCERT class 12 book 1 chemistry...Solids chapter!
It's that ferri magnetic have some moment..but the net moment of all particles cancels out!
In paramagnetic...it has unpaired electrons..so there is a moment!